# Getting coodinates of a location by user tagging place in map

Tags: node.js, express, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Mapbox GLJS with node.js for geolocating. But when a user adds a place Mapbox doesn't get that location right. So I'm looking for a feature of Mapbox, if it exists, that The user instead of typing the location in input, sees a map and tags that exact location in that minimap, and I get the coordinate of that location in the backend and do my stuff with that. Do you what I should do? Does Mapbox have that feature? It's like getting an Uber when you set the location of yourself and where you want to go.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GL JS will include `.lngLat` info on pretty much any mouse events that fire. These example should give you a good idea of where to start:

- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mouse-position/
- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/drag-a-point/

---

⚠️ disclaimer: I currently work at Mapbox ⚠️

Comment: Thanks, they were useful, I could make it with them. Just a little question. How can I put some handlers for a more user-friendly interface? Like I want the marker or point to move to the place user double clicks instead of grabbing it to the desired location.

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to checkout the Mapbox GL JS docs. There is a plethora of map events, and you should be able to find the one that suits your use case. Based on your comment, I'd say start with: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map.event:dblclick